# Building a graph from a text file in C

Tags: c, data-structures, graph

I'm having a hard time trying to build a graph from a text file. We were given the following .csv file:

```
Alice;Beto;Julia;Maria;Flavio;Katia
Beto;Alice;Cleiton;Maria;Duda;Flavio
Cleiton;Beto;Katia
Duda;Beto;Katia;Olivia
Eloa;Julia;Katia
Flavio;Alice;Beto;Greta;Katia
Greta;Flavio;Maria;Katia
Helio;Katia
Julia;Alice;Eloa;Katia
Katia;Alice;Cleiton;Duda;Eloa;Flavio;Greta;Helio;Julia;Maria
Luis;Nairo
Maria;Alice;Beto;Duda;Greta;Nair;Katia
Nairo;Luis;Olivia
Olivia;Nairo;Duda
Paria;
```

The first name of each line stands for a vertex, the rest of the line are the vertexes the first one is connected to. How can I read from that file and transform it into a graph? The mechanisms of the graph itself are almost done, but this whole reading thing is driving me crazy!

Comment: What is your *specific* problem?

Comment: If your graph data structure is almost done, you probably  need  a  mechanism to  identify a node by name, right?

Comment: So you need a graph structure *and* a hashtable structure to build it with.

Comment: Which part of reading is driving you crazy?

Comment: After playing with a tutorial on reading text files (which should allow you to read and print all the names in your input file) - what is your question?